# authentication in Cassandra 3.0 is broken

Tags: authentication, cassandra

On a new installation of cassandra 3.0.20 on redhat 7 I can not list roles. I have tried the option of fixing `/etc/alternatives/cassandra/cassandra.yaml` with...

```
authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator
```

and then restart the service.

still when I run a simple command like `LIST ROLES` I get the following error.

> cassandra@cqlsh> list roles;
>
> Unauthorized: Error from server: code=2100 [Unauthorized] message="You have to be logged in and not anonymous to perform this request"

Comment: Try also setting the CassandraAuthorizer.

Comment: @Aaron I did add authorizer: CassandraAuthorizer  and restarted, still no success

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that systemctl was not completely stopping cassandra due to weirdness with Redhat 7 and the init file. Therefore the changes to my cassandra.yaml were not taking effect.

Once I killed cassandra, made a proper cassandra.service and restarted the desired settings took effect, and I am able to run operations like "LIST ROLES;" normally.